# Run ADB shell on OS X

Tags: android, string, macos, command-line, adb

I want to enter a simple adb shell command, so I navigated to `...\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe`, and opened it. However, I am unable to type in it!

[image]

What is the solution?

Comment: This is because you haven't opened the terminal of MAC instead of that you have opened the Java. Open terminal and then you will be able to type adb.

Comment: I'll go ahead and say that OSX doesn't run exe files

Answer (score 12):

`.exe` files are executable files for the Windows OS. They will not work on OSX.

There is a program called Terminal that is installed in OSX that you can use to run the `adb shell` command. You must open up a Terminal and navigate to the directory that is shown in your screenshot, and then you can run the command 
`./adb shell` and it should work.

Alternatively, you can use the Terminal in Android Studio to perform the same operation.

Comment: How do I navigate to the directory shown in my screen shot?

Comment: Sorry if it is a "noob" question, I am new to mac

Comment: No problem @RuchirBaronia. The command to navigate directories (another name for folders) is called `cd`. Think of `cd` as double clicking on a folder in File Explorer. When you open up the Terminal you will be in your home directory, then you can type `ls` (list) to show you all of the directories available. When you see the one that you would like to go to type `cd <Name of the directory you want to go into>` and repeat until you see `adb` when you type the `ls` command.

Comment: Here is a more thorough [guide](http://www.westwind.com/reference/os-x/commandline/navigation.html)

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I change my directory to platform-tools on a mac terminal: 
Search the finder for "platform-tools". Then right-click on it, and left-click on "get info". You'll see a little window pop up with all the info for that folder. 
Copy the "where", which is the file path.

Then paste into your terminal like this:

```
cd /Users/[user-name]/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
```

Be sure to add `/platform tools` on after pasting the path to the folder.

Then hit <kbd>return</kbd>. Your terminal should then be pointed to that folder and you can invoke the adb commands by using `"./adb [whatever command]"`. 
Or you can invoke adb shell commands: for example let's say you want to enable Analytics Debug mode on an Android device. Use the following command:

```
adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app [your_package_name]
```